# Statistical programming in ATOM editor - No Output Displayed

Tags: python, atom-editor

I'm completely new to Python programming and started working with non-statistical programming part. But I'm stuck while running statistical program. Here's a little background.

I've installed Python (3.8.0) and Atom editor, Windows 10. Additional packages installed are: Script, linter, auto-complete-python,auto-runner. I've installed Anaconda & Jupyter as well (but not thought of using it).

By doing this, I'm able to run non-statistical programs. However when I try to run statistics in Python and try a very simple code as follows:

```
import statistics

a = [0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 9, 15]

statistics.mean(a)
```

the output is not as expected. **There is no statistics generated**. The message displayed is as follows:

**[Command: python -u C:\Users\mehta_ni\AppData\Local\Temp\atom_script_tempfiles\757f8490-0b72-11ea-8e1a-29b65544ec4b]
[Finished in 0.418s]**

Can someone help, what mistake I'm doing - **Do I need to make any changes in environment variable, etc?**

I tried finding solutions online but couldn't figure out. I plan to import foll. 5 basic libraries once the above issue is fixed:

(1) random
(2) statistics
(3) math
(4) datetime
(5) csv

**FYI -**

Python installed in the path - C:\Users\Python

Anaconda installed in the path - C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3

Atom installed in the path - C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Python

Comment: what is your expected output? you have to print anything to get an output. Try `print(statistics.mean(a))`

Comment: Hey Luigigi - Thank's for the correcting me. Your solution works.